# Why thickness of metal thin film will affect reflectance?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection

The reflection of the interface of two layers is described by Fresnel's equations. For instance, the reflectance of an Al bulk at 1 micron is around 0.9, this is the reflectance of the interface between air and Al, and it shouldn't change no matter how thick the Al layer is, as long as the interface is still the same. Now assuming we polish the Al to a 1 nm thin film from the other side, and keep the air-Al interface intact. Then the reflection can be lower than 0.9. The refractive index of Al doesn't change, and the smoothness of the interface is still the same, why the reflectance can be different?

Comment: The construction of the Fresnel equations relies on the assumption that the polarization surface current at the interface has zero thickness, but this is obviously just an approximation. If your medium is thinner than this surface current (i.e., as akhmeteli points out, thinner than the skin depth) then the Fresnel equations are at least susceptible to change.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : I think another assumption one uses to derive Fresnel formulas is important: that there is no wave* falling on the surface in the direction opposite to that of the incident wave. Such wave* is important for a layer of finite thickness.

Answer (score 1):

A few side points and notes about the conditions:

- 1 nm Aluminum thin film is challenging and most likely not achievable by only polishing. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcc.9b05564
- Nonetheless I understand what you are trying to achieve here

> For instance, the reflectance of an Al bulk at 1 micron is around 0.9

Reflectance is also wavelength dependent, which leads to:

> this is the reflectance of the interface between air and Al, and it shouldn't change no matter how thick the Al layer is, as long as the interface is still the same.

This is also not always correct, there is a small but important dependence of sample thickness and refractive index: https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-27-24-34803&id=423174 At least here proven for zinc selenide thin films (but I have also seen comparable behavior for polymeric thin films).

By putting thin films on reference materials, you will start seeing the formation of thin film interefence patterns. As the sample grows thicker, thus increase the reflectance oscillations (this would also occur under different angles, particularly interesting in ellipsometry for the Brewster angle).

[image: Thin film interference]

For very thin films the effect is also non-negligible.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252978783_Experimental_study_of_the_optimal_metal_film_for_surface_plasmon_resonance

Answer (score 0):

I believe 1 nm is of the order of magnitude of the [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) for visible light in aluminum, so part of light gets to the farther surface of the Al layer and partly exits the layer, so the reflectance decreases. Remember that reflectance typically depends on the thickness of the layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Are there any references you know talking about how to calculate the reflectance and transmittance in this case? I've tried to find them online but I got nothing...

Comment: @user221757 : https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a098940.pdf seems relevant. It's quite doable, but not a walk in the park.

Answer (score 0):

You are decreasing the number of electrons in the path of the beam, so you can think of it as decreasing the cross-section of the light to the electrons. But, this is only noticeable on the order of the skin depth.

Reflectance (R), transmittance (T), and absorbance (A) must satisfy R + T + A = 1. That is, energy must be conserved. If reflectance decreased then T + A increased. Obviously, absorbance decreased too, so it's the increase in transmittance that decreased reflectance.